# Google Play Fused Location and setInterval

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

I'm trying to get the position of the device by *Google Play Fused Location*, and all it's ok, but don't seems to respect the intervals of request:

```
LocationClient myLocationClient;
myLocationClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
myLocationClient.connect();

...

LocationRequest myLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
myLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
myLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
myLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
myLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(myLocationRequest, this);
```

whether I write 10000, 100000 or one million on **setInterval** and **setFastestInterval**, the request is fired every time the location change.

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: Need more code to understand the contextual problems